Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR while signin Google in react native with react-native-google-signin (GoogleAPI Cloud)
I have problem signing in with google, I used react-native-google-signin (GoogleAPI cloud)
I tried both webClient and Android but not change 
I have displayed and selected the account, but when the Api returns [Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR]


I have fully setup it as instructed. Let me know if anything special is needed.
I thank you
i try more but not work :((
